Modified Markov chain
Let $x_t, y_t$ be to independent Markov chains with non-zero transition probabilities and two states {0, 1}. $t$ is a positive integer. $x_0 = 0, y_0 = 1$ .  Process $a_t$ is defined as $a_t = c^{x_t} + d^{y_t}$, where $c, d$ are real-valued constants. I should find all $c, d$, such that increments of process $a_t$ have zero covariance for all $t_1 \leq t_2 \leq t_3 \leq t_4$.
I supposed that the only answer is $(c, d) = (1, 1)$ and tried to divide the covariance of increments in two parts, where first depends on $c$ and second depends on $d$ and suppose that chain has stationary distribution. However, it doesn't help very much.
So, I need to show if $c^{x_{t_2}} - c^{x_{t_1}}$ and $c^{x_{t_4}} - c^{x_{t_3}}$ are independent and identically-distributed (I do not know how and not sure that is not wrong) or to find an other way to solve the task.
